# Разница между assembly и nuget в asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Попробовал разделить типовое asp.net core 2.0 приложение по отдельным проектам.

Решарпер бодро подеркомендовал нужные неймспейсы, всё подключил, работает.

Я правда чисто случайно заглянул в references и увидел, что оказывается там всё организовано совсем по-другому, чем в классических приложениях:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Привычных packages, которые лежали рядом с проектом нет – NuGet лежат где-то в недрах c:\progra files\dotnet\sdk, да и привычные assemblies туда же съехали.

Хотел уточнить: есть ли какая-то разница с точки зрения того, как подключать библиотеки. Вот допустим, Resharper подключил мне Identity.Stores как assembly, а может быть стоило его подключить как nuget?

И я вряд ли хотел бы тащить в DataAccess весь AspNetCore.All (я так понимаю, это здоровый мега-пакет со всем возможным набором asp.net core, б-р-р-р), можно ли как-то только нужные подключить в другие проекты? (Заходил в менеджер пакетов, но не увидел каких-то похожих опций)

Comment: По поводу `AspNetCore.All` - это набор пакетов на время разработки приложения, его добавили начиная с версии `.Net Core 2.0`, т.к. всех задалбало добавлять практически одни и те же пакеты в проект во время разработки в `.Net Core 1.0`. Когда приложение собирается для Publish, то из этой кучи реально в дело идет только то, что было в using.

Comment: Ужас, как вставляются ссылки через относительные пути:       <HintPath>..\..\..\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.entityframeworkcore\2.0.1\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.dll</HintPath> - не понимаю, зачем. Каждый раз проект в git мелкие такие изменения будут если менять уровень папки.