# Следует ли наследоваться от IdentityUser в классе модели (сущности)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity-2

Есть вот такой пример архитектуры приложения от Microsoft для проектирования ASP.Net Core MVC приложения: https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnWeb

То есть там создаются отдельные библиотеки классов `.Net Standart`, в которых описана вся часть, не касающаяся Web'а: отдельно для сущностей и интерфейсов, отдельно для инфраструктуры БД.

Я хочу написать что-то вроде форума, соответственно, мне нужна сущность, которая содержит в себе ссылку на автора сообщения. 
Для авторизации в ASP.Net Core приложении используется [ASP.NET Core Identity](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity).

А значит пользователь у меня будет представлять из себя класс (либо его наследник) `IdentityUser`, но он находится в `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore`.

И если я напишу сущность так, то у меня будет зависимость от пространства имён Web'а.

```
public class Message
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int AuthorId { get; set; } //внешний ключ БД, по которому будет заполняться свойство автора
    public virtual IdentityUser Author { get; set; }

    // other fields..
}
```

Опыта разработки ASP.Net Core MVC приложений у меня мало, так что прошу совета. Как следует поступить в данной ситуации?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Когда-то задавался подобным вопросом, так как хотел добиться того, чтобы классы предметной области зависели только от базовых примитивов, а тащить сторонние библиотеки (пусть даже и от ключевого вендора asp.net) не хотелось. И особенно было непонимание, зачем в предметную область тянется зависимость от EntityFramework.

Тем не менее всё решается достаточно просто и вендор вполне об этом позаботился.

Класс IdentityUser находится в неймспейсе `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity`, этот класс вы положите в проект доменной логики.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

namespace MyCompanyName.MyProjectName.Domain.Models
{
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<int>
    {
    }
```

А работа с базой у вас будет в отдельном проекте и туда мы вынесем ApplicationDbContext:

```
using MyCompanyName.MyProjectName.Domain.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace MyCompanyName.MyProjectName.DataAccess
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, int>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }
```

Два последних using'а тянутся именно для работы с базой, а identity тянется опосредованно через модель.

Выглядеть всё целиком будет примерно следующим образом:

[image: Domain project]

Обратите внимание: asp.net core вместо десятков пакетов всё собрано в один Microsoft.AspNetCore.All - это сделано для удобства разработчиков, чтобы не тратить время на поиск и подключение нужных пакетов (в классическом asp.net это занимало достаточно много времени).

По этому поводу я тоже отдельно переживал, но мне @Bulson [объяснил](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/795908/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%83-assembly-%d0%b8-nuget-%d0%b2-asp-net-core#comment1255868_795908), как это работает:

> По поводу AspNetCore.All - это набор пакетов на время разработки
>   приложения, его добавили начиная с версии .Net Core 2.0, т.к. всех
>   задалбало добавлять практически одни и те же пакеты в проект во время
>   разработки в .Net Core 1.0. Когда приложение собирается для Publish,
>   то из этой кучи реально в дело идет только то, что было в using.

Comment: Думал подключить только `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity` вместо `Microsoft.AspNetCore.All`, т.к. второй не поддерживает проекты .Net Standart, но после установки `using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;` студия всё ещё не видит `IdentityUser<int>` ( http://pastexen.com/i/vMNQ9gkLMC.png ). Видимо придётся переписывать проект под .Net Core

Comment: В .Net Core (после обновления до версии 2.1) после подключения `Microsoft.AspNetCore.All` заработало с тем же using'ом без ничего дополнительного =/

Comment: При сборке решения возникли два вот таких варнига: https://pastebin.com/itLLqFsw Он что сам себя установил в Program Files, а теперь спотыкается о пробел в пути? Выбора пути при установке SDK я не заметил =/

Answer (score 1):

Да, следует. Если этого не сделать - вы не сможете использовать стандартные классы `UserStore` и `IdentityDbContext`. Что же до проблемы с "пространством имен Web'а" (что бы это ни значило) - то тут есть очень простое решение.

Просто перенесите вашего наследника `IdentityUser` в нужное вам пространство имен.

Comment: Имеется ввиду, наверное, что модель потянет за собой пакет `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore` и все его зависимости, которые составят почти весь AspNetCore целиком